# GDM: Select Unity Desktop

Tags: 18.04, gdm

I have installed ubuntu-unity-desktop package from my ubuntu 18.04LTS installation and I wish to change into unity or any other desktop environment I have installed in it.

But on the login screen I find no option to select between gnome and unity. Do you know how I will enable this option into GDM?

Comment: at login screen didt you find gear icon?

Comment: No I cannot see the gear Icon.

Comment: seems desktop session not installed properly..

Comment: i generally install `sudo apt install unity` in my Ubuntu 18.04 and after a reboot i can select Unity from login screen..

Comment: The gear icon on the login screen will only be shown after selecting your username, or typing in your username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you reboot the computer? The change to take effect needs your computer to be rebooted afterwards, a gear icon will be shown and then you can select the appropriate "GUI" you desire.